# Run prettier on windows

Tags: windows, prettier

I want to add prettier into scripts in `package.json`.

Reading at the docs, it suggests doing the following using the [cli](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html)

```
In practice, this may look something like:

prettier --single-quote --trailing-comma es5 --write "{app,__{tests,mocks}__}/**/*.js"
```

It works on mac / ubuntu but getting the following error message on windows.

```
[error] No matching files. Patterns tried: 'src/*.js' !**/node_modules/** !./node_modules/**
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Comment: Can you share exactly what was the command you added to package.json and what is the file structure of your project?

Comment: Try referencing your file paths relative to the package.json file you're calling the script from. Prettier can't find your files because it's looking in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 11):

For Windows you have to escape the `"`, in the `package.json` will look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "prettier": "prettier --single-quote --trailing-comma es5 --write \"{app,__{tests,mocks}__}/**/*.js\"",
},
```

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this issue most recently myself.

Here's what I did:

in my package.json file i added this to the scripts section:

```
  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.js",
  }
```

Note that the path does not have its own set of quotes. That solved it for me

Comment: This helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was regex problem, and I simply change from `"format": "prettier --write '**/*.{js,json}'"` to `"format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,json}\""`