# Getting an error 'No files matching the pattern were found' when using prettier

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-standard

I found this answer how to format code using [prettier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57629631/415078)

Here is what I've done

```
npm i prettier -g
prettier --write \"./**/*.{js,html}\"
```

Got an error `[error] No files matching the pattern were found: ""./**/*.{js,html}"".` any ideas how to fix? do you think it is because I installed the `prettier` globally (in the answer it is installed locally)?

So how would you use pettier when it is installed globally then?

Comment: You don't need to escape quotes when you use command from cli.

Comment: Run `ls` and `pwd`, what was the output?

Comment: What is the actual question here? Prettier is running. Do those files indeed exist and it's not finding them? Or are you expecting it to pass if they do not exist?

Answer (score 10):

the problem is with the quotes

I was using

```
prettier --write 'src//**/*.{js,jsx,json}'
```

here is how I fixed mine

```
prettier --write src//**/*.{js,jsx,json}
```

this was for errno 2

Comment: Weirdly the reverse fixed it for me

Answer (score 10):

One solution to this problem was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078281/run-prettier-on-windows) : and actually worked for me. Notice I am on Windows machine, so am not sure how it will behave on others. Just remove anything before and after the expression (quotes):

```
prettier --write ./**/*.{js,html}
```

Answer (score 9):

Probably the quotes are wrong. It should probably be:

```sh
prettier --write "./**/*.{js,html}"
```

without the backslashes.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on using a windows computer. Removing the double quotes worked for me.

this the script on **package.json**

```
 "prettier-format": "prettier --config .prettierrc src/**/*.ts --write"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a prettier script setup in `package.json`, you'll need to wrap the filepath in quotes, escape double quotes or use single quotes:

```json
"prettier": "prettier 'src/**/*'"
"prettier": "prettier \"src/**/*\""
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to suppress the error message, because you don't have any matching files yet, then you can use the `--no-error-on-unmatched-pattern` flag when executing Prettier:

```bash
$ prettier --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern --write \"./**/*.{js,html}\"
```

Answer (score -1):

what worked for me is installing touch command globally using this command

```
npm install touch-cli -g
```

then create your .prettierrc file using the touch command

```
touch .prettierrc
```

put simple configuration in the .prettierrc file like

```
{ "trailingComma": "es5","tabWidth": 4,"semi": false,"singleQuote":true}
```

then in the package.json file write the following script

```
  "scripts": {
"prettier":"npx prettier --config .prettierrc \"src/**/*.js\" --write"
             }
```

then run the script using npm command

```
npm run prettier
```

Comment: Why would you install touch? It has nothing to do with the question. It just creates a file. Also I think prettier should look for .prettierrc by default without passing --config.